# My lighting stays the same when I go indoors?

Tags: shaders, lighting, cel-shading

My problem can be seen [here](https://streamable.com/18524e) notice how the shadows don't change intensity or color when moving indoors to the cave. The only thing that changes is the highlights when I move under the directional light. I was thinking about adding global illumination but I don't think that would work with a toon shader. How can I get my lighting to become darker once I enter indoors e.g a cave. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to setup light probes so your dynamic objects receive bounced light information from the static environment.

As explained in the manual: [Light Probes for moving objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightProbes-MovingObjects.html).

Comment: Is this possible for a toon shader though?

Comment: According to your video, your character receives lighting information. so yes as long as it is not an Unlit shaded material. this should work.

Comment: Ya I thought so as well but no matter which shader I try that says it supports GI, it just doesn't seem to work. The lighting gets a bit more realistic e.g in the world but my model stays the same. Light probes don't seem to work even when I enable them.